# What causes DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET and how do I fix the error?

Tags: 16.04, dns

I've been having this issue in Chrome and have tried so many different things to make it stop and none of that worked. This error appears randomly and disappears for a while once I disconnect from my connection and reconnect again.

Comment: Only in Chrome? Anyway, it suggests a problem at your router more than anything else. How are you connecting, i.e., what connection is that you disconnect and reconnect?

Comment: It happened in other browsers as well. I connect using wifi from a modem.